# PostgreSQL find where string contains exact string

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a table with values like:

- "Head of HR"
- "Assistance of management"

If I have the string like "hr" I would like to find the row "Head of HR".
A simple "LIKE %hr%" would not be precise enough, because other rows with a string containing "hr" would be found as well.
I guess I need some kind of regex.

Maybe someone could give me a hint, how to write it.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE col ~ '\yHR\y'
```

The `\yHR\y` regex will match a `HR` as a whole word (the `\y` is a word boundary, it matches the start or end of a word).

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/EPP64871):

```
CREATE TABLE tabl1
    (s character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tabl1
    (s)
VALUES
    ('Head of HR'),
    ('Assistance of management'),
    ('CHROME')
;

select * from tabl1 where s ~ '\yHR\y';
```

Result:

[image]